# Mod flag comment no longer shows action taken

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, comment-flags

It used to be that when, as a moderator, you flag a comment it would get insta-deleted, the reason logged, and **the comment deletion would be reflected on the screen**.

The functionality appears to be working as in the comment is deleted, but you can **no longer see that anything happened** because the comment is still sitting there like an impertinent bum until you refresh the page.

Comment: Check the JavaScript console... any errors there maybe?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope no errors on the JS console (Chrome 27 here).

Comment: Hmm.. obviously there is AJAX here. Open the Network tab of Chrome dev tools while you delete a comment and you should see the request and the response being sent back from the server. Check the contents of the response, it should be JSON - anything funky there?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope nothing funky. JSON response is `{"Success":true,"FlagType":"CommentObsolete","ResultChangedState":true}`. Like I said the comment does get deleted so the chat with the server works, but whatever hook or callback is supposed to remove the comment _in situo_ after getting confirmation isn't doing it's job.

Comment: OK, leaving this in the trusty hands of the devs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, if you change a property name, the serialized JSON also changes and checking for the old property name in JavaScript no longer works.

Who knew?

Fixed in the next build.